# VBA Find Formula

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am using the following code to search in the A column of a row for a name. If the name is found, it is placed in a column 2 over. I am trying to search against a list of names rather than one name. The names are listed in sheet1, I am searching text stored in column A on sheet4. Each row has a paragraph of text I want to search. When a match is found, the matching name(s) is put in cell c of the same row.

```
   Sub test()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1, rng2, cel1, cel2 As Range
Dim i, lrow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

'i only assumed that your data is both in column A of sheet 1 and 2
lrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lrow) 'this contains the names
lrow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:A" & lrow) 'this contains list of text you want to search

i = 0
For Each cel2 In rng2
    For Each cel1 In rng1
        If InStr(cel1.Value, cel2.Value) <> 0 Then cel1.Copy ws2.Range("c1").Offset(i, 0): i = i + 1
    Next cel1
Next cel2

End Sub
```

Cheers!

Comment: So, you want to search column A, for any cells that **contain** (not equal??) any value in a list of values, found in another range, and if match is found place the word from the list in column C? (not the value of that matching cell??)

Comment: I can't see how this does ANYTHING different then my solution besides being slower. Could you provide a sample of your data, both search values and look up values, (just a sample), and a sample of desired output? You should not need any loops for this and defiantly not 2.

Comment: I need this as a macro, it would read text (paragraph) in sheet4 cell a1, a2... and search for names that are listed in cell a1 sheet1. When matched, name is put in sheet4 cell c1, c2 ....

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does.... As the picture shows, is the problem because all words on sheet1 are in the same cell?

Answer (score 1):

If my comment is correct then this should work for you:

say I start with this set up:

[image]

I would first add my look up values to a named range as follows:

[image]

then you can add this code:

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
        .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(LookUpValues,RC[-2]),LookUpValues),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and this should result in the following:

[image]

Comment: this is not quite want I am looking for. I modified my response, should be more clear. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

this is another way to get what you want but not really using formula.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1, rng2, cel1, cel2 As Range
Dim i, lrow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'i only assumed that your data is both in column A of sheet 1 and 2
lrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lrow) 'this contains the names
lrow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:A" & lrow) 'this contains list of text you want to search

i = 0
For Each cel2 In rng2
    For Each cel1 In rng1
        If InStr(cel1.Value, cel2.Value) <> 0 Then cel1.Copy ws1.Range("B1").Offset(i, 0): i = i + 1
    Next cel1
Next cel2

End Sub
```

I proposed above approach since you are open to using VBA.
hope this is what or somewhat close to what you want.

Comment: I have edited my post, code is close, but it is not searching the text in sheet 4 and returning matches, just seems to be copying the list of names from sheet 1 and placing in sheet4 starting at c1

Comment: haha yes it does that. that's how i understand your question. Can you help me out and post sample data and expected results. Also, we might need to improve the code and remove the loop especially if your working on big set of data.